# Handle different layout and different orientations

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an application I want to adapt to tablets and handheld devices

- When handheld device is in portrait or landscape I want to display `ListView` and when list item is selected I start another activity.
- When tablet device is in portrait - see above.
- When tablet device is in landscape I want to display `ListView` in one part of the screen and selected item content in another part of the screen. Basically something like this: [image]

How should I achieve that? I was thinking different activities and layout resources for each orientation. But I have a feeling that there is a smarter and better way.

Of course I could stuff everything in one activity somehow but it doesn't feel right. Nor looks nice :)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to achieve can be done using `Fragments`. Here is an [example](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html) depicting the use of `Fragments`.

To communicate between fragments see this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. But how about "communication" between Fragment1 and Fragment2. For example list item is clicked so how Fragment1 should know if it there is Fragment2 or should it start separate activity?